# not understanding how the output is generated

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, parentheses, operator-precedence

i expect the output (or value of silly) to be `36`. but what i get is `14`. this is fixed when i add parentheses: `#define THING (4+2)`.

but i still want to know what is happening when there are no parentheses and why im getting an output of `14`
.
the following is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define THING 4+2

int main(void)
{

    int silly = THING * THING;
    printf("%d", silly);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
THING*THING = 4+2*4+2 = 4+(2*4)+2 // because of higher precedence of * than +
            = 4+8+2 = 14.
```

Do remember that MACROs are exactly replaced(substituted) into the code.

Answer (score 3):

The macro is literally inserted in place of `THING`.

`THING * THING` is `4+2 * 4+2` is `4 + (2 * 4) + 2` which is 14.

If you want the result to be 36 than you need to define your macro wrapped in parenthesis:

```
#define THING (4 + 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because macros are (almost) the same as text replacement. `int silly = THING * THING;` is converted by the preprocessor to `int silly = 4+2 * 4+2;`, and order of operations means that's processed as `4 + (2 * 4) + 2`, not `(4 + 2) * (4+ 2)`.

Answer (score 2):

You need parentheses because order of operations is interfering. Macros just replace text, and so without parentheses, the operations are not being evaluated in the order expected.

```
THING * THING ----> 4 + 2 * 4 + 2 = 14
```

So, once you use parentheses, this fixes it because it becomes:

```
THING * THING ----> (4 + 2) * (4 + 2) = 36
```

This is explained [in this preprocessor tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cpreprocessor.html).